# XmlTextReader ignores CheckCharacters=false when Normalisation is on

Tags: c#, xml

I have implemented my XmlTextReader with overridden setting for CheckCharacters. Something like this:

```
class MyXmlTextReader : XmlTextReader
{
    public MyXmlTextReader(TextReader input) : base(input)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Settings
    /// </summary>
    public override XmlReaderSettings Settings
    {
        get { return new XmlReaderSettings { CheckCharacters = false }; }
    }
}
```

When I use it in normal scenario with invalid xml data everything works fine:

```
var sr3 = new StringReader(xml);
var xr3 = new MyXmlTextReader(sr3);
var obj3 = (MyObject)ser.Deserialize(xr3);
```

But as soon as I turn on normalisation, I start getting InvalidCharacter exceptions:

```
var sr3 = new StringReader(xml);
var xr3 = new MyXmlTextReader(sr3);
xr3.Normalization = true;
var obj3 = (MyObject)ser.Deserialize(xr3);
```

Is there a way to have normalisation, but at the same time ignore invalid xml characters?

Here is a sample application to reproduce the problem:
https://gist.github.com/ncksol/29bd6490edd0580c25f7338b417b37d3

Comment: Can you provide some minimal XML to reproduce?

Comment: Sure thing. Here you go - https://gist.github.com/ncksol/29bd6490edd0580c25f7338b417b37d3

Comment: Why would you inherit from `XmlTextReader` instead of just passing `XmlReaderSettings` to `XmlTextReader.Create`? I'm not sure this way of overriding `Settings` is even legal, given that it does *not* return the settings the reader was created with.

Comment: Because XmlTextReader.Create returns you XmlReader that cannot be cast to XmlTextReader and therefore I cannot turn on Normalisation

Comment: This appears to be a shortcoming in the implementation. The `XmlTextReaderImpl` this returns *does* have a `Normalization` property (and `XmlTextReader` is nothing but a wrapper over `XmlTextReaderImpl`), but that property is `internal` and there is no access to the constructors of `XmlTextReaderImpl` that take `XmlReaderSettings` either. I'm not sure if there's a clean way of doing this. If you don't mind relying on the implementation, then you could use `XmlReader.Create(...)` and set the `Normalization` property through reflection.

Comment: Hm... That's not the most ideal implementation, but I guess it might suffice. Thanks for your help. Would you mind copying your comment as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a shortcoming in the implementation:

- `XmlReader` has no `Normalization` property.
- `XmlReader.Create` allows you to pass `CheckCharacters` as a setting, but since it returns `XmlReader`, you can't control the normalization through it.
- `XmlTextReader` (actually wrapping `XmlTextReaderImpl`) has `Normalization`, but no public `CheckCharacters` property, and no way of accepting `XmlReaderSettings`.
- Finally, `XmlTextReaderImpl`, which does all the *real* work, can do both normalization and omitted character checking, but due to all of the above, there is no public path to configuring it that way.

If you don't mind relying on the implementation in this case, it can be done through reflection:

```
var sr3 = new StringReader(xml);
var xr3 = XmlReader.Create(sr3, new XmlReaderSettings { CheckCharacters = false });
// xr3.Normalization is not accessible
xr3.GetType()
    .GetProperty("Normalization", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .SetValue(xr3, true);

var obj3 = (MyObject)ser.Deserialize(xr3);
```

Hacky, but still far preferable over implementing `XmlTextReader` from scratch which, given all the cleverness in the implementation, is not something to undertake lightly.

Note that `XmlReader.Create` is *not* contractually obligated to return an instance of a type that has a `Normalization` property, it just happens to do so in the current implementation.